# Creating Numpy-Arrays without iterating in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a numpy array with shape (2,3) filled with floats.

I also need an array of all possible combinations of X and Y Values (their corresponding position in the array). Is there something like a simpe function to get the indices as a tuple from a numpy array in which I don't need to have for-loops iterate through the array?

Example Code:

```
arr=np.array([np.array([1.0,1.1,1.2]),
              np.array([1.0,1.1,1.2])])
indices=np.zeros([arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1]])

#I want an array of length 6 like np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1], [1,2]])
#Code so far, iterates though :(
ik=0
for i in np.arange(array.shape[0]):
    for k in np.arange(array.shape[1]):
        indices[ik]=np.array([i,k])
        ik+=1
```

Now after this, I want to also make an array with the length of the 'indices' array containing "XYZ coordinates" as in each element containing the XY 'indices' and a Z Value from 'arr'. Is there an easier way (and if possible without iterating through the arrays again) than this:

```
xyz=np.zeros(indices.shape[0])
for i in range(indices.shape[0]):
    xyz=np.array([indices[i,0],indices[i,1],arr[indices[i,0],indices[i,1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.ndindex`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html#numpy-ndindex):

```
indices = np.ndindex(arr.shape)
```

This will give an iterator rather than an array, but you can easily convert it to a list:

```
>>> list(indices)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Then you can stack the indices with the original array along the 2nd dimension:

```
np.hstack((list(indices), arr.reshape((arr.size, 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to achieve this ... A possible solution is the following.

The first problem can be solved using `np.unravel_index`

```
max_it = arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1]
indices = np.vstack(np.unravel_index(np.arange(max_it),arr.shape)).T
```

The second array can then be constructed with

```
xyz = np.column_stack((indices,arr[indices[:,0],indices[:,1]]))
```

**Timings**

On your array `timeit` gives for my code `10000 loops, best of 3: 27.7 µs per loop` (grc's solution needs `10000 loops, best of 3: 39.6 µs per loop`)

On larger arrays with  `shape=(50,60)` I have `1000 loops, best of 3: 247 µs per loop` (grc's solution needs `100 loops, best of 3: 2.17 ms per loop`)

Answer (score 0):

For your indices:

```
indices = np.concatenate((np.meshgrid(range(arr.shape[0]), range(arr.shape[1])))
```